# Select2 list display issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently working on this [website](http://www.onetechsearch.com/tech/category/all/?search=&images=1&to=), and my select2 list is not displaying properly when it comes to desktop, but it displays as a field when it comes to the mobile version. How can I make look like a list?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cat = ["C"];
  $("#cat").select2({
    data: cat
  });
});
$('select').select2({
  minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
  placeholder: function() {
    $(this).data('placeholder');
  }
});
```

```css
select {
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.styleselect {
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  background-image: url("http://s21.postimg.org/nx05vn15f/dropdown_style.png");
  background-position: 117px center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 140 px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
.styleselect select {
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 0 0 1px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 4px;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 140 px;
}
.styleselect select option {
  background-color: #DFD3C3;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 140 px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div class="styleselect">
  <select data-placeholder="Select a Category" name="cat" id="cat" class="select2" multiple>
    <option selected value="all">All Categories</option>
    <option value="EN">England</option>
    <option value="GR">Greece</option>
    <option value="US">USA</option>
    <option value="IT">Italy</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you ever heard about browser console? please man you've more than 18 error in the console. the `select2` is just one of them.

Comment: I know what the browser console is. My problem right now is how to properly display the list

Comment: Here is jsfiddle and works perfectly : https://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/nbhrnyy9/

Comment: @JohhnySins I guess, you can image(mockup) to show us, how do you want to show it